# How to add a dot break in between words in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, text

I'm working on a project and I need to know how to break words with a dot similar to how youtube adds dots in between elements, such as.[image: Example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can copy the dot and use it directly in a string like this

```
String finalString = "$string1 • $string2";
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use an [interpunct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpunct). check the table on the lower part of the wikipedia entry to see different types of interpuncts.

```dart
  ...
  Text('$views views \u2981 $date');
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```dart
String string1 = "ALI";
String string2 = "Shan";
String dotString = "$string1 • $string2";
```

output: "ALI . Shan"